# За что конкретно отвечают REST и SOAP?

Tags: http, rest, soap, протоколы

Прочитав пару статей в интернете, единственное, что я понял, так это то, что:

1. REST - архитектурный стиль. Может работать с xml, json...
2. SOAP - протокол. Может работать только с xml.

За что конкретно отвечают REST и SOAP? Что они делают? Насколько я понимаю, они устанавливают "правила" передачи информации между клиентом и сервером. Но разве за это не отвечает HTTP протокол?

P.S. Понятно, что вопрос немного "общий". Но мне было бы неплохо понять хотя бы общий механизм работы REST и SOAP, без всех подробностей

Comment: Эти «правила» находятся на разных уровнях. Очень упрощённо говоря, HTTP устанавливает правила того, как прописать ссылки, заголовки и тела запросов-ответов, но не указывает, какое конкретное содержимое внутри них должно быть (можно любое), а REST и SOAP регламентируют, какие конкретно ссылки-заголовки-тела внутри HTTP допустимо использовать

Comment: Вот Когда мы набираем адрес в браузере, то он направит серверу запрос http. В ответ сервер вам отправит html-страницу с помощью того же протокола http. Но этот протокол пригоден не только для пересылки гипертекста, но и файлов, и других форматов данных. Так вот если внутри http-пакета содержится xml особого формата - это soap. Если json особого формата - это rest.

Comment: Вообще говоря, rest тоже бывает на основе xml, но фишка rest в том, что формат данных полностью определяется вами.